# How to use Rxjs startWith to provide default initial values to withLatestFrom using outer observable's value?

Tags: angular, rxjs

this works, but I don't want to use null for initial values of startDate and endDate, I need to initialize with the values from another observable,  the userInfo$ in the code below:

```
export interface IUserInfo {
    UserEntryStartDate: Date;
    UserEntryEndDate: Date;
    // ...
}


public userInfo$: Observable<IUserInfo>;

private dateFilterSubject = new Subject<{
    startDate: Date;
    endDate: Date;
}>();

        this.userInfo$
            .pipe(
                withLatestFrom(
                    this.dateFilterSubject.pipe(
                        startWith({
                            startDate: null,
                            endDate: null
                        })
                    )
                )
            )
            .subscribe(([userInfo, dateFilters]) => {
                // ... do stuff
            }
```

This is what I'd like to do

```
        this.userInfo$
            .pipe(
                takeWhile(() => this.active),
                withLatestFrom(user => // userInfo from outer observable
                    this.dateFilterSubject.pipe(
                        startWith({
                            startDate: user.UserEntryStartDate,
                            endDate: user.UserEntryEndDate
                        })
                    )
                )
            )
            .subscribe(([userInfo, dateFilters]) => {
                // do stuff
            }
```

It even gives correct autocomplete and typing on the `user` parameter,
however I get an error on the subscribe of:

```
Type 'Observable<{ startDate: Date; endDate: Date; } | { startDate: Date; endDate: Date; }>' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `BehaviorSubject` for the same. Here you can set the default value.

Example:

```
private user = new BehaviorSubject<string>('john');
```

In your case:

```
private dateFilterSubject = new BehaviorSubject<{
  startDate: Date;
  endDate: Date;
 }>({{value}});
```

For more info please refer:

https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/subjects/behaviorsubject

Hope this will help.

Comment: I don't see how this lets me initialize the BehaviorSubject with values from the userInfo$ observable?